# Using file path from a cell in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, path

I'm working with .xml files in VBA, and I'd like to make file paths dynamic, since the macro has to run on many different .xml files, so that there's no need to edit the code every time I'm using it. I've tried the following, which makes the right path of the file be printed correctly in the immediate window, but it doesn't open it. I'm referencing Microsoft XML, v3.0.

How can I dynamically edit the SelectionNameSpaces line of the code too?

```
Sub openxml()
Dim Obj as DOMDocument
Dim xmlpath as String

Set Obj=New DOMDocument
Obj.async=False
Obj.validateOnParse=False

xmlpath=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B4").Value
Debug.Print xmlpath
```

'''Obj.SetProperty "SelectionNameSpaces", "xmlns:ns0='http://update.DocumentTypesSchema.myfile.Xml' " '''

```
If Obj.Load(xmlpath)=True Then
   Msgbox ".xml uploaded"
Else
   Msgbox ".xml not uploaded"
   Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you copy the returned path (from Immediate Window) and run the code again, but instead of `xmlpath=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B4").Value` you use `xmlpath = "path copied from Immediate Window"` does it work as you need? I suppose that your path only looks being correct, but it shouldn't...

Comment: Yes, it does work correctly. So the path name isn't the problem, but the upload of the file itself. I have other file formats in the text, such as .xlsx, .csv, and I'm facing exactly the same problem.

Comment: As the code is working (just did a quick test), there must be a problem with either the XML file name or the XML file itself. Sure that the value in your cell doesn't contain any extra characters, like spaces, newline, tab or the like? Try using `Debug.Print "[" & xmlpath & "]"` or use the `trim`-function

Comment: So, do you say that replacing the suggested line with the string copied from Immediate window it works? I am afraid that you are so sure it **should work** and you did not tested in the way I recommended, no offence. It cannot work in that way, if extracting from the cell it doesn't...

Comment: @FaneDuru yes, I tested the code exactly in the way you suggested.

Comment: In such a case, there is no logical explanation. It should be exactly the same string and it should work exactly the same... If "the path name isn't the problem" how can it work if you do not extract it from the cell value?

Comment: @FunThomas Fixed it, i was including "..." in the range, since I thought the file path should be given as a string.